# trying to get svg paths to flow smoothly

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, svg

I'm working on an SVG with flowing animated svg paths.  This SVG implementation is based on another reference SVG implementation.  My problem is that the lines on the reference implementation flow smoothly forever.  However, my implementation appears to encounter subtle but noticeable hiccups in its flowing process.  Here's the original implmentation:

https://jsbin.com/hodoseb/edit?html,output

Here's my code:

https://jsbin.com/jitufih/edit?html,output

Here's my SVG:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kfroff5fyidd0ay/map-path-1213.svg?dl=0

Any idea why my version has hiccups in its flow animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dashed path `NortheastSoutheastFlow` is overwriting the `flowline` CSS class' `stroke-dasharray` attribute. So instead of using `10,4`, it uses `12,4` (search for `stroke-dasharray="12,4"` in your SVG). That causes each line dash and it's space after to have a length of **16**, not 14. Therefore, you should be interpolating to animate from 0 to 16 in your `animateThis` function:

```
return d3.interpolate(0, 16);
```

With that change, the animation is smooth. Alternatively, you can just change the `stroke-dasharray` attribute in the SVG to be `10,4`, as in the original implementation. Your `flowline` CSS class is being ignored, as is not referenced in the SVG.